# Cannot read properties of undefined 'populate' - NodeJS, Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

When creating a new message, I immediately want to `populate` the message document and send it back to the user. However when I do `message.populate()`, I get returned an error saying `populate` is undefined.

Here is my code:

```
let message = await createMessage(chatId, req.user._id, messageText)
// Error thrown here when trying to populate the message
await message.populate({ path: "sender" })


async function createMessage(chatId, senderId, messageText) {
        let message = await Message.create({
            sender: senderId,
            chat: chatId,
            messageText,
        )}
   
        return message
}
```

Why is `populate` undefined? Thanks.

Comment: if you do `console.log(message)` what do you get?

Comment: The undefined here is not populate but message, so this error is telling that message is undefined. You need to console log the response of `createMessage`, there might be an error there @Herb

Comment: What is `Message`?

Answer (score 0):

here is the corrected code.

```js
let message = await createMessage(chatId, req.user._id, messageText);
await message.populate({ path: 'sender' }).execPopulate();

async function createMessage(chatId, senderId, messageText) {
  let message = await Message.create({
    sender: senderId,
    chat: chatId,
    messageText,
  });

  return message;
}
```

**Explanation:**

To populate an existing document. you need to add **execPopulate()** at the end.

```js
await message.populate('sender').execPopulate();
```

and you don't need to add object in populate if you are not passing the fields to select. for example if you want to include only chat and sender then you will need an object like

```js
await message
  .populate({ path: 'sender', /* select: 'name age email' */ })
  .execPopulate();
```

and If you want to populate multiple fields. you can pass an array to populate. like:

```js
await message.populate(['sender' /* 'receiver' */]).execPopulate();
```

and if you want to populate multiple fields with control what to select you can pass objects in arrays like:

```js
await message
  .populate([
    { path: 'sender', select: 'name email' },
    { path: 'chatId', select: 'bla bla bla' },
  ])
  .execPopulate();
```

in your case:

```js
await message.populate({path: 'sender'}).execPopulate();
```

and

```js
await message.populate('sender').execPopulate();
```

and

```js
await message.populate(['sender']).execPopulate();
```

all will give the same result.